# Tokyo Skyliner return ticket

Tags: trains, japan, tokyo

Keisei offers online discount tickets for non-japanese citizens.

https://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/e-ticket/en/

I will be visiting Tokyo landing at NRT, so a return ticket seems to make sense.

However, I cannot find any info about the "return" part of the ticket. The online purchase system only has one "date of trip" field.
You have to exchange you e-ticket for a real ticket at the airport.

**Does that mean I have to choose a date/time for the return part at the desk on the arrival date?
What if I miss the train on the departure date, can I board the next one?**

Comment: Side question: any risk of the train being full a Saturday morning (my arrival date) and having to wait 30min for the next one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the order page says,

> If you are purchasing a round-trip ticket, we will give you a Ticket
>   Exchange Voucher for the ticket of your return trip at Keisei Electric
>   Railway Exchange Locations.

The "date of trip" field refers to the beginning of your trip.

I assume that the voucher in question is not going to have a date printed on it (since it doesn't say otherwise), and that you rather go to a Keisei station on the day you're leaving and exchange it for a ticket right before going to the platform.